# Package Images does not exist

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to get the image uri from camera but im getting this error

> Package Images does not exist

`Images.Media.insertImage` didn't work. I don't know what is the correct way to do this.

Here is my code.

```
Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
camerabitmap = Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageBitmap);
dynamic.setImageBitmap(camerabitmap);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for something like `Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1);`

Comment: refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388586/get-uri-from-camera-intent-in-android