# ImageView Load ImageUri

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I have `ImageView` with image choosen by user from gallery:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

and:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        try {
            final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.img);
            img.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            //
            ImageURI = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(imageUri));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Becouse, I need to save Uri of this image to use it later I've created `String` ImageURI which value is assigned to String Value of imageUri (as you can see above)
But when I try to load this image to imageview;

```
ImageView.setImageUri(ImageURI);
```

image doesn't load. I don;t get any error.
Sample Uri which I was using: **content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2storage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2Camera%2FIMG_20190521_005650.jpg**

Comment: You do not have access to the content later: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html

Comment: Aren't this permissions enought?
   ` <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Comment: No, because you do not have a file. You have a `content` `Uri` from the MIUI gallery app on that device.

Comment: maybe duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388586/get-uri-from-camera-intent-in-android)

Comment: But even if I add: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);'
the images doesn't show